# What is wrong with my CSS - selects more then it should?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<div id="top">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell number one content...</td>
        <td>Cell number two content...</td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Presumably, this CSS should select the entire first cell blue and the second red:

```
  div#top table tbody tr:first-child {
      background-color:blue;
   }
   div#top table tbody tr + tr {
      background-color:red;
   }
```

Instead, this is what happens:
[image]

Comment: You should set up a JSFiddle so that the sample rendering actually relates to the code you gave us. As far as I can tell, your rendering is consistent with your CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite. :first-child in your case means "a TR which is the FIRST CHILD of a TBODY". it doesn't mean "the first child element of a TR" (the TD).

As such, you're applying the blue to the table row, not the first td that happens to be a child of tr.

if you want the first td only, then:

```
div#top .... tr td:first-child { background-color: blue; }
```

Comment: A `tr` which is the first child of its parent, which may or may not be a `tbody` (even if the HTML guarantees it's a `tbody`, CSS does not). I know I know, I'm being a prick :)

Comment: hence the "in your case", but yeah, I know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use CSS3 if you want to alternate row colors:

```
tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#eee; }

tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want second-child only you need to use `nth-child(2)`. What you are using now, `tr + tr` is affecting every `tr` that follows a `tr`, or, every `tr` after the first.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `td:nth-child(1)` for the first column and `td:nth-child(2)` for the second.

```
div#top table tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
      background-color:blue;
   }
   div#top table tbody tr:nth-child(1)  td:nth-child(2) {
      background-color:red;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `nth-child`?:

```
div#top table tbody tr:nth-child(2) { 
  background-color:red; 
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HGdzx/